# Filters vs silently appending a criteria to a user search query in Lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I read an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878758/filters-in-lucene) question and found that there are two ways to further narrow down the results of a user's search query without any user intervention:

1. By silently modifying a query
2. Applying Lucene filters

I understand both the above techniques at implementation level but not at conceptual level. I have following questions:

1. What is the order in which the Lucene apply filters. Is it before or after the query? If I go by name, I guess, it should be after.
2. When to use one technique over the other?
3. Is there any performance difference between the above two techniques when there is no functional difference?
4. Which technique is more suitable when documents have user permissions associated with it and the user should see only his/her documents in the results of his search?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the order in which the Lucene apply filters.

Does it really matter? If you have n independent filters, the overall result will be product of these filters running AND function on top of each other.

> Is it before or after the query?

Strictly speaking, they work hand in hand. Here's an excerpt from `IndexSearcher.java` (Lucene ver 3.4)

```
while (true) {
  if (scorerDoc == filterDoc) {
    // Check if scorer has exhausted, only before collecting.
    if (scorerDoc == DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
      break;
    }
    collector.collect(scorerDoc);
    filterDoc = filterIter.nextDoc();
    scorerDoc = scorer.advance(filterDoc);
  } else if (scorerDoc > filterDoc) {
    filterDoc = filterIter.advance(scorerDoc);
  } else {
    scorerDoc = scorer.advance(filterDoc);
  }
}
```

How I understand this code is that both filter/scorer iterators advance forward, and if the filter is ahead of scorer, then scorer is used and vice versa.

> When to use one technique over the other?
>
> Is there any performance difference between the above two techniques when there is no functional difference?

I normally prefer adding extra bits to the query as I believe this is faster than post-query filtering (even if you use `QueryWrapperFilter`). But you need to make sure that customer has no way to do Lucene query string injection. In some cases performance implications are negligible and filter option is preferred as it is easier to filter result set than add query element(s).

> Which technique is more suitable when documents have user permissions associated with it and the user should see only his/her documents in the results of his search?

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866089), it has been discussed before.

Answer (score 1):

If certain criterias do not change and will be re-used multiple times in between each index update, then a `Filter` is usually the way to go.

For example I usually use Filters for user permissions. After each index update the cached Filter gets recomputed only once until the next update. That works really well if your index is not realtime.

Another use case for Filters is to avoid `BooleanQuery.TooManyClauses` exceptions.

Comment: Hint: you can call `BooleanQuery.setMaxClauseCount(count)` (static method) to increase this limit.

Comment: yeah but your still stuck at Int32.MaxValue-1, and its better imo to use a Filter to avoid setting the max clause count to a huge value if possible, as in that scenario, a Filter will definitely be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hesitating between appending a boolean clause to a query and using a filter, it probably means that you should use a filter.

Filters are better than boolean clauses because they don't need to score. As a consequence, they are faster and can be cached (pretty useful if you often filter with the same conditions).

Lucene doesn't apply filters after the query. On the contrary, it first checks filters in order not to score (scoring can be costly) documents that would get filtered out anyway.

Comment: can anyone explain the -1?

Comment: +1 for providing more details about filters. The last statement that you have made about scoring makes logical sense to me. Could u please point me (if you know of any) to any online reference that helps me to understand more about filters.

Comment: Can you comment on my answer? From the code I have looked at, it looks like filtering and scoring are happening both interchangeably, depending on the situation. P.s. downvote isn't mine.

Comment: @Arnand I don't know of good resources. The best way to know how it works is probably to go into the details of IndexSearcher.search(Query, Filter, int)

Comment: @mindas Actually, there are several strategies (see https://svn.eu.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/FilteredQuery.java) to intersect the query with a filter either with a leap-frog approach or using the filter as a random-access bit set. In both cases, scoring is only performed if a document matches the filter, this is why I said that filtering is happening before query evaluation although not fully correct.